# How to find out where $MANPATH is set?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, manpage, zsh

How can I find out in which configuration file the environment variable `$MANPATH` is set? Is there a way to backtrace the values?

I am aware of that I can grep through the whole file system using `find` or `grep`. I am using `zsh` most of the time instead of `bash`. I run Ubuntu Precise.

Answer (score 7):

As others already wrote Ubuntu doesn't set the `MANPATH` by default. You can edit your `.profile` and add the `MANPATH` as you like. But where does Ubuntu get the information about your manpath?

This information is set in `/etc/manpath.config`. The package `man-db` uses this information to configure the paths for man. The environment variable `MANPATH` has precedence over the file `manpath.config`. The file has the following (and probably more) entries:

```
MANDATORY_MANPATH /usr/share/man
MANPATH_MAP /usr/bin /usr/man
DEFINE troff groff -mandoc
```

The  first line tells a software which automatically generates the `MANPATH` what directories it should contain. Typically `/usr/man`, `/usr/share/man` and other are set up here.

Next is a mapping from the users `PATH` to the correct `MANPATH`. If a user has `/usr/bin` in his `PATH`, the `MANPATH` should contain `/usr/man` in my above example.

The `DEFINE` value has some default set of arguments and programs for pager utilities.

Comment: Is there any way to *add/append* to the default search path? Or is `export MANPATH=$(man -w):/new/path` the best way?

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu by default doesn't set `$MANPATH`, so your search can be limited to your `~/.{ba,z}shrc` and the files they include

The search path compiled into the man command can be seen with `man -w`. On my system (12.10), this returns `/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man`

Comment: How do I know that Ubuntu does not set `$MANPATH` itself?

Comment: Create a new user, log in as that user, `echo $MANPATH`.

Comment: Okay. Lesson learned. Your suggestion that the configuration must be in one of the dotfiles is partially true. I found what I was looking for there. But there are configuration files also in `/etc/zsh/zshrc`. I could have manually changed those without remembering it.

Answer (score 1):

Try running

```
zsh -x -ls -c "exit" 2> shell-startup-output
```

After running this command, the file `shell-startup-output` should show you each file being sourced when the shell starts.  You can then examine each of these files to see which one sets `$MANPATH$`.

If this doesn't work for you, the only other way I know to do it is to use `grep` or `find`.

Comment: This should work in `bash` as well as `zsh`.

Comment: It outputs the paths but not the names of the configuration files - or am I misunderstanding you?