# Does apps installed via "snap" has man page?

Tags: snap, manpage

Just installed `kubectl` via snap:

`sudo snap install kubectl`

But, `man kubectl` shows:

> No manual entry for kubectl
>   See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.

Wondering does apps installed via `snap` have man page by default?
If yes, how to see it?

Comment: Applications installed via snap have a manpage...if the developer includes a manpage. It's not required. Seems like a bug report to the snap developer.

Comment: `find /snap -type d -name 'man*' 2>/dev/null` will show you `man` directories, `ls -lR /snap/kubectl` will show you what's in the snap.

Comment: @user535733 How to include the man page for `kubectl` for example, and how to see it ???

Comment: "How to include" a file in a snap is up to the snap creator, not the user. That's why it's a bug report.

Comment: @user535733 Does that means the app might don't have the man related content with it, thus I can't see it.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "...if the developer includes a manpage"

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/764835/how-can-i-view-man-pages-for-apps-installed-via-snaps

Comment: @waltinator `ls -lR /snap/kubectl` shows there is no man page for `kubectl`, the 2 commands are useful, thanks.